# Install Windows 8 on MBPr with Boot Camp

Tags: macos, windows-8, boot-camp

I am trying to Install Windows 8 on my MBPr via Boot Camp.
I get the USB flash drive setup via Boot Camp in OSX, created the partition, reboots and installs files and features. When it gets to "Finishing install" it reboots twice, and then I get to a screen where I can only see 1 quarter of the screen - the rest I blacked out - see below image

I tried 4-5 times now, each with the same result. I can see the mouse pointer in the blue area, and move it around - but only in the blue area. The black area is "disabled", for lack of a better word. I tried keeping it there for 6 hours without touching anything, thinking it was perhaps still installing, but nothing changed.
In the first couple of install screens, I see everything as I should - meaning 100% of the display is visible.

I know Boot Camp does not officially support Windows 8, but I see a lot of people who got it running with no major issues - and none like the one I am getting.

Any ideas? I am running the latest version of OSX and version 5.0.1 of Boot Camp (standard on my OSX, did not do anything do upgrade it myself).

Screenshot of error: [image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Windows 8 is not official supported by Boot Camp at this time.  There is no ETA when that support will come.  **This error seems like a pure driver problem.**  My guess is Windows actually BSOD and what you see is half the BSOD.